Translate C enum into Zig namespaced enum
Given the following C code:
// h.h

typedef enum E {
  A,
  B,
  C
} E;

Zig translates this to
pub const A: c_int = 0;
pub const B: c_int = 1;
pub const C: c_int = 2;
pub const enum_E = c_uint;
pub const E = enum_E;

This is a correct translation, because enums in C aren't namespaced, however I prefer enums to be namespaced for several reasons which I won't get into here.  Is there a way to get Zig to generate
pub const E = enum {
  A,
  B,
  C,
};

instead?

Zig doesn't have any methods to modify translate-c output. To improve it, either you have to write manual bindings or wrap the translate-c results with your own enums.

Not with translate-c and that's largely because the translate-c feature of the zig compiler is first and foremost responsible for use via @cImport in zig files.
But you can with comptime reflection of the @cImport.
Typically if I'm building a wrapper around a C lib and I want to warp it with a zig version that defines off the C version.
const c = @cImport({ @cInclude("foo.h"); });

pub const Foo = struct {
    pub const Flags = enum(u16) {
        A = c.FOO_OPTS_A,
        B = c.FOO_OPTS_B,
        //...
    };
};

Although you could go step further and build this with comptime since you can build struct, union or enum, types that have no decls.
Given this header file:
enum Foo {
  FOO_OPTS_A = 1,
  FOO_OPTS_B = 2,
  FOO_OPTS_C = 3,
  FOO_OPTS_D = 4,
};

This zig code will compile it into an enum that's usable like if you hand rolled it.
const std = @import("std");
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("enum.h");
});

fn buildEnumFromC(comptime import: anytype, comptime prefix: []const u8) type {
    comptime var enum_fields: [1024]std.builtin.Type.EnumField = undefined;
    comptime var count = 0;

    inline for (std.meta.declarations(import)) |decl| {
        if (decl.name.len < prefix.len + 1) {
            continue;
        }

        @setEvalBranchQuota(10000);
        if (std.mem.eql(u8, decl.name[0..prefix.len], prefix)) {
            enum_fields[count] = .{
                .name = decl.name[prefix.len + 1 ..],
                .value = @field(import, decl.name),
            };
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return @Type(.{ .@"enum" = .{
        .tag_type = u16,
        .fields = enum_fields[0..count],
        .decls = &.{},
        .is_exhaustive = true,
    } });
}

const FooOptions = buildEnumFromC(c, "FOO_OPTS");

pub fn main() void {
    const flags: FooOptions = .A;

    switch (flags) {
        .A => std.debug.print("Got A\n", .{}),
        .B => std.debug.print("Got B\n", .{}),
        .C => std.debug.print("Got C\n", .{}),
        .D => std.debug.print("Got D\n", .{}),
    }
}

The best part is, because we can declare it as exhaustive ourselves, if there is any change to the C header file, adding or removing values will cause the compiler to error out on the switch in main.
